# ListView add more items

Tags: android

I have a ListView and set a SimpleAdapter to show some formated items, then how could i add other items to the items Listview with the old format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to extend the `BaseAdapter` class and create a method `addItem()` that adds your item to the `BaseAdapater`'s item model. Then you should call `notifyDatasetChanged` to have your listview updated.

There are tons of examples of this online and on SO.

Answer (score 4):

If you add more data to the `List` you supplied in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor and then call `mySimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method afterwards the `ListView` will refresh itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But how's more, i do not like to refresh itself, because i need the listview to keep the position it scrolled. I want to make it just as i could load more datas.

Comment: You have a `List` yes. eg. `myList`.  To add data to it, call the method `myList.add(myNewData)`.  If you do that and do not call `mySimpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the `ListView` will not refresh.  `myNewData` of course depends on what you are sticking in your `List`.

Comment: If you update the backing data and call 'notifyDataSetChanged', it will keep the scroll position as best it can.